# Same height for rows in 2 column layout

Tags: html, css

I want a 2 column layout like this:

[image]

As you can see, each "row" has the same height as the other one. I am trying to code this, but without luck. I tried bootstrap, that works but it is not responsive (the second column does not go below the first obviously).

I want it to behave like this:

[image]

Then I tried to set the height of each part by javascript, that worked, but the height stays the same even after resizing to mobile device's width and I really hate this method.

Is there any normal/easy way to do this?

Comment: have a look at `display:flex` it will do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` for this.

To make it so that the columns go under each other when the screen is resized, use media query's

See example snippet below or [This JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jhj0wz2s/) to see how the responsiveness works

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox-container > div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 300px;
}
.flexbox-container > div:first-child {
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.flexbox-container2 > div {
  height:100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.flexbox-container{display:block;}
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container flexbox-container2">
  <div>
    <h3>Row 1 - Column 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Row 1 - Column 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div>
    <h3>Row 2 - Column 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Row 2 - Column 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flexbox-container flexbox-container2">
  <div>
    <h3>Row 3 - Column 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Row 3 - Column 2</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is similiar to the bootstrap solution I mentioned, but the problem is, how do I put the second column under the first one on small-width devices? Because with this solution, it does the following on smaller devices: "col1_row1, col2_row1, col1_row2, col2_row2" instead of "col1_row1, col1_row2, col2_row1, col2_row2". I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: You could use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to achieve that

Comment: I am using media queries, but the thing is, how can you manage to move second column under the first one, if this solution is in a fact "3 rows" and not "2 columns".

Comment: This solution creates a "2 column layout" as you specified.. This is what the question was asking. I am not too sure what you want

Comment: In that case, you can use `display:block` instead of `flex`

Comment: Thanks to Abhishek Pandey for adding the media query. Now it addresses your question @KarlosOtruba